# В чем отличия расширений .phtml и .html.php?

Tags: php

Есть ли различия у этих расширений? Если да то какие, и в каких случаях используют то или другое расширение?

Comment: конечно же у этих **суффиксов** есть отличия. да хотя бы длины строк сравните — в одном шесть символов, в другом — девять.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Начнём с того, что это: `.html.php` не расширение) По факту тут написано расширение `php`. Отличий может вообще не быть, если сервер настроен на обработку обоих расширений как интерпретируемых. По умолчанию, обычно, `php` железно интерпретируется, а остальное может быть донастроено. Как по мне, использование `phtml` может быть оправдано разве что для использования в представлениях данных, в шаблонах и т.д., а `php` исключительно с пхп кодом, типа контроллеров, сервисов, моделей и т.д. Т.е. эдакое визуальное раздеделние в проекте.  Но по факту phtml нафиг не нужен. Только для визуального морального удовлетворения и какого-то своего перфекционизма разделения. Как по мне - можно использовать везде файлы с расширением `php` и не париться. А сервер можно настроить на что угодно.

Comment: то есть, `.html.php` - тот же `php файл`, только в названии файла приставка `.html` это просто подсказка что в этом файле есть html разметка?

Comment: @Георгий  да.. так. кому-то видимо удобно.....А расширение это **всегда** то, что написано после последней точки..... вы же файл можете назвать `моя.прикольная.работа.php` Это же не значит, что у вашего файла такое полное расширение

Comment: Благодарю за быстрый и полный ответ!